# Typeahead: Observable.create(...).mergeMap is not a function

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, angular7

I'm using ngx-bootstrap 3.0.1 and I've upgraded my application from Angular 6.1.3 to 7.0.0 and got error **mergeMap is not a function**:

> CfComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError:
>   rxjs_Observable__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.Observable.create(...).mergeMap
>   is not a function

code used looks like that:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import { TypeaheadMatch } from 'ngx-bootstrap/typeahead';
................
 this.dsTA = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
        observer.next(this.cl.TA);
      }).mergeMap((token: string) => this.getAsObservTA(token));
```

with angular 6.1.3 code worked

older :"rxjs": "^6.2.2","rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
new:   "rxjs": "^6.3.3", "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3"

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.2
Node: 10.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 7.0.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.9.0-rc.3
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.9.0-rc.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.9.0-rc.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.9.0-rc.3
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.0-rc.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.2
@angular/cdk                      6.4.7
@angular/cli                      7.0.2
@ngtools/webpack                  7.0.0-rc.3
@schematics/angular               7.0.2
@schematics/update                0.10.2
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.3
webpack                           4.21.0
```

thanks for any clue

Comment: Why don't you do the right thing, and use rxjs as it's supposed to be used since angular 6 (i.e. use pipeable operators), instead of using the old "compatible" way?

Comment: seems using pipe solve the problem.thanks:   this.dataSource = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
      observer.next(this.asyncSelected);
    })
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((token: string) => this.getStatesAsObservable(token))
      );

Answer (score 4):

RxJs has changed in version >= 6.0.0

Below are things you need to do for making your code working.

```
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

................
 this.dsTA = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
        observer.next(this.cl.TA);
      }).pipe(mergeMap((token: string) => this.getAsObservTA(token)));
```

---

Please a look at the below url for details looks into the migration

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md